# Automatic implicit generation of ctors utilising move semantics

Tags: c++, c++11, constructor, default, move-semantics

Let we have a class with n fields. Each field can be moved. So do we have to explicitly define 2^n constructors?

The example with n=2:

```
struct A{
 std::vector<B> a;
 std::shared_ptr<B> b;
 A(std::vector<B> &a, std::shared_ptr<B> &b):a(a),b(b){};
 A(std::vector<B> &a, std::shared_ptr<B> &&b):a(a),b(std::move(b)){};
 A(std::vector<B> &&a, std::shared_ptr<B> &b):a(std::move(a)),b(b){};
 A(std::vector<B> &&a, std::shared_ptr<B> &&b):a(std::move(a)),b(std::move(b)){};
};
....
A aaa({{},{}}, shared_ptr<B>(new B()));
std::shared_ptr<B> b = ....;
A bbb({{},{}}, b);
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can work around it by having a perfect-forwarding template constructor:

```
struct A {
    std::vector<B> a;
    std::shared_ptr<B> b;
    template <typename AA, typename BB> A(AA&& a, BB&& b) :
        a(std::forward<AA>(a)), b(std::forward<BB>(b)) { }
};
```

If you need stricter parameter types requirement, you can also add `enable_if` or `static_assert`.

Here's a little explanation how perfect forwarding works:

```
void func1(int&&) { }
template <typename A> void func2(A&& t) {
    func3(t);
    func4(std::forward<A>(t);
}
template <typename B> void func3(B&&) { }
template <typename C> void func4(C&&) { }

int foo;
const int bar;

func1(foo); // ERROR
func1(bar); // ERROR
func1(std::move(foo)); // OK

func2(foo); // OK, A = int&, B = int&, C = int&
func2(bar); // OK, A = const int&, B = const int&, C = const int&
func2(std::move(foo)); // OK, A = int&&, B = int&, C = int&& <- note how && collapses to & without std::forward
```

Comment: Why do you use ```AA&& a``` in the prototype? Will this function also work in the case of lvalue references?

Comment: With template type parameters, "&&" has a special meaning: it will make a compiler deduce the template parameter to exactly same type as argument passed to a function (including all qualifiers).

Comment: I've finally managed to fix all typos in my reply update :) Please check

Comment: Thank you. [This article](https://isocpp.org/blog/2012/11/universal-references-in-c11-scott-meyers) about refs collapse was also useful.

Answer (score 0):

You're defining the special member functions incorrectly, copy/move constructor is not defined in terms of class members, it defined in terms of the class.

instead of

```
class_name(const member_1&, ..., const member_n&)
class_name(const member_1&&, ..., const member_n&&)
```

you have to define your copy/move constructor as:

```
class_name(const class_name&) // copy-constructor
class_name(class_name&&) // move constructor
```

and inside it, use copy/move semantic. see [c++draft class.copy](http://eel.is/c++draft/class.copy)

Comment: I didn't mean to copy of the object of class A. I meant constructing the class using rvalues without copying.

Comment: like ```A aaa({{},{}}, shared_ptr<B>(new B()));``` or ```std::shared_ptr<B> b = ....; A bbb({{},{}}, b);```